# Custom property in renderTpl

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I need to show some extra text under a date picker when it's expanded but not for every date picker in my application.

I am overriding the Ext.picker.Date component and modifying the renderTpl property to add in the extra html. After that i am trying to wrap the new html in an if condition so it's only visible when a boolean property is set when creating the component

```
Ext.define('overrides.picker.Date', {
override: 'Ext.picker.Date',

showExtra: false,

renderTpl: [
    '....existing html for picker here...',

    '<tpl if="showExtra">',
        'extra picker text',
    '</tpl>',
]

});
```

So, by default showExtra is false and then my idea was to specify this to be true when using the date picker on a page.

```
items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        value: this.effectiveDate,
        showToday: false,
        showExtra: true
      },
```

The condition is never being met, even when i specify showExtra to be true in the value above the renderTpl property. How can i pass in the value so the condition is met ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [renderData](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-renderSelectors) to set custom properties for your tpl

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    value: this.effectiveDate,
    showToday: false,
    renderData: {
        showExtra: true
    }
},
```

Or a more cleaner way would be to do that inside your overriden code. Have a look at the original beforeRender() in Ext.picker.Date. Some properties like "showToday" are moved to renderData there:

```
...

Ext.apply(me.renderData, {
    dayNames: me.dayNames,
    showToday: me.showToday,
    prevText: me.prevText,
    nextText: me.nextText,
    days: days
});

....
```

In your override file you could do something like:

```
beforeRender: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);

    Ext.apply(me.renderData, {
        showExtra: this.showExtra
    });
}
```

In that case you don't need to set your porperty inside the renderData. Just write:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    value: this.effectiveDate,
    showToday: false,
    showExtra: true
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The property is being set in the component now but it always seems to be the default value (false). The new value i'm passing in through the renderData object is not being set. Please check the following fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1la4

Comment: You are setting the showDateLegend on the datefield but want to use it on the date picker. These are two separate components. Have a look at the Ext.form.field.Date source. There is a createPicker() method which creates the picker and passes all kinds of properties. You could override that method

Comment: I updated my answer. No need to use renderData if you are updating renderData in the override.